# mvc 4 cannot implicitly convert IEnumerable<anonymous>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am very new to mvc and trying to get the concept. I am following [this instruction](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/06/13/many-to-many-relationships-with-ef.aspx) to deal with many many relationship. But I create an interface and entity framework and use ninject to bind them together. Instead of 'books'and 'users' (like in the tutorial), I use 'groups' and 'users'. I read many posts about the same error but they dont seem to solve my problem

```
public interface IGroups
    {
        IQueryable<Group> Groups { get; }
    }

public class EFGroups : IGroups
    {
        private EFDbContextMainDb1 context = new EFDbContextMainDb1();

        public IQueryable<Group> Groups
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

 public class EFDbContextMainDb1 : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Group> tblGroup { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Group>().ToTable("tblGroup");

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

    }

public class GroupListViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<GroupNetworkUser> GroupNetworkUsers { get; set; }

    }

GroupListViewModel model = new GroupListViewModel
            {
                GroupNetworkUsers = testRepo.Groups.SelectMany(
                        group => group.Users,
                        (group, user) => new { 
                            userName = user.vch_NetworkID

                        }
                    )
            };
```

The error applies to "GroupNetworkUsers = testRepo.Groups.SelectMany(...". and says

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Pho.Domain.Entities.GroupNetworkUser>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\visual_studio_project\pho\pho\Controllers\GroupsAndUsersController.cs    58  37  Pho.WebUI
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a new GroupNetworkUser object.  Currently you are building an anonymous object

```
GroupListViewModel model = new GroupListViewModel
        {
            GroupNetworkUsers = testRepo.Groups.SelectMany(
                    group => group.Users,
                    (group, user) => new GroupNetworkUser {  // <-- Changed this line
                        UserName = user.vch_NetworkID    
                    }
                ).ToList()
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it to a list:

```
GroupListViewModel model = new GroupListViewModel
            {
                GroupNetworkUsers = testRepo.Groups.SelectMany(
                        group => group.Users,
                        (group, user) => new { 
                            userName = user.vch_NetworkID    
                        }
                    ).ToList()
            };
```

Comment: thanks for the response. it doesn't work, though. now the error says Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Pho.Domain.Entities.GroupNetworkUser>'